# Howto write https sever no certificate in golang?

Tags: go, https

I am trying to write a server logic which takes 'https' request but client does not have any certificate, how do I write it?

Comment: http://goroutines.com/ssl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could go two different directions depending on what you're actually asking.

If you're asking how to host `https` requests without the *server* having a certificate, that's impossible.  `https` requests mean that the connection is secured by SSL/TLS, which necessarily requires a server certificate to function.

If you're asking how to host `https` requests without requiring *clients* to have certificates, that's another matter, and in fact is the default behavior of the `http.Server`.  You actually have to set the `https.Server` field `ClientAuth` (for example, to `http.RequireAndVerifyClientCert`) in order to actually require those certs.  If you don't set this field, the default value is `http.NoClientCert`, which allows client connections without certificates, and doesn't validate the certs even if they are presented.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so if server does not validate the certificate even then we have to generate `cert` and `key` file.

Comment: The client doesn't need to provide the certs at all, no.  The _server_ still needs valid cert files, but the client doesn't unless you set the `http.Server.ClientAuth` field.

Answer (score 0):

Https requests require SSL Certificates.. you can create a self signed one, but you should get a real, valid certificate for any production ready server.

Just 1 way to make a self signed cert: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-self

Comment: Sounds more like he's asking about SSL without client certs (totally doable, an in fact the default behavior), not SSL without server certs (not possible).

Comment: ah - i read as 'client' being who he was implementing for. you're totally right @Kaedys